# Chart not rendering, just an empty div is added

Tags: reactjs, charts, vite, scatter-plot, react-google-charts

```
<div>
    <Chart
      chartType="ScatterChart"
      width="80%"
      height="400px"
      data={[
        ["Year", "Sales", "Expenses"],
        ["2004", 1000, 400],
        ["2005", 1170, 460],
        ["2006", 660, 1120],
        ["2008", 1030, 540],
        ["2009", 1000, 400],
        ["2010", 1170, 460],
        ["2011", 660, 1120],
        ["2012", 1030, 540],
      ]}
      options={{
        title: "Company Performance",
        curveType: "function",
        legend: { position: "bottom" },
      }}
    />
  </div>
```

> I'm using **npm i react-google-charts** to use charts within a react app, when I run the application not seeing the chart in the UI also when i inspect can see just the empty div being rendered. No console errors or application error, app works fine. It'd be helpful if i can know what am i missing or doing wrong in the approach

Comment: When I try to reproduce your code in sandbox, it works fine here https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/agitated-shape-yxpvmq?file=%2FApp.tsx.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the parent container of the chart has sufficient width and height. If the container size is not set or set to zero, the chart may not be visible.

```
.chart-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

And in your JSX file:

```
<div className="chart-container">
    <Chart
      chartType="ScatterChart"
      width="80%"
      height="400px"
      data={[
        ["Year", "Sales", "Expenses"],
        ["2004", 1000, 400],
        ["2005", 1170, 460],
        ["2006", 660, 1120],
        ["2008", 1030, 540],
        ["2009", 1000, 400],
        ["2010", 1170, 460],
        ["2011", 660, 1120],
        ["2012", 1030, 540],
      ]}
      options={{
        title: "Company Performance",
        curveType: "function",
        legend: { position: "bottom" },
      }}
    />
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried this, the container takes up the given dimension but the chart isn't rendered. I tried adding a loader text, the loader text is displayed but not the chart itself.

Comment: Double-check the format of your data and if there are any conflicts or compatibility issues with other dependencies in your project. It looks correct in the provided example, but make sure that the actual data in your application follows the same structure.